# dplyr & tibble - Create a new column according to values in a list column

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a tibble dataframe as follows:

```
data = tibble(X = c("a", "b", "c", "d","c"), 
          Y = c("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1","c1"), 
          Z = c("a2", "b2", "c2", "d2","c2"),
          all = list(c("a"), c("b"), c("c", "c1"), c("d", "d2"), c("c", "b2")))
```

I want to create a new column "result" such that for each row :
- if the "Y" value is in "all" => result equals the Y value
- if the "Z" value is in "all" => result equals the Z value
- else result equals "none"

I've tried the following code with the dplyr syntax.

```
data %>%
mutate(result = case_when(Y %in% all ~ Y,
                          Z %in% all ~ Z,
                          TRUE ~ "none"))
```

It doesn't work as expected and returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  X     Y     Z     all       result
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr> 
1 a     a1    a2    <chr [2]> none  
2 b     b1    b2    <chr [1]> none     
3 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> none  
4 d     d1    d2    <chr [2]> none
```

When I'd like to obtain :

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  X     Y     Z     all       result
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr> 
1 a     a1    a2    <chr [2]> none  
2 b     b1    b2    <chr [1]> none     
3 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> c1  
4 d     d1    d2    <chr [2]> d2
```

**EDIT**

One problem is to unlist the values in the column list as stated by [Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah). But even with this solution, the behavior is like working on the column list will consider all the values of the column and not only those of a row.

Here is what I obtain with the proposed solution and the edited data :

```
data %>%
    mutate(result = case_when(Y %in% flatten_chr(all) ~ Y,
                              Z %in% flatten_chr(all) ~ Z,
                              TRUE ~ "none")) 

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  X     Y     Z     all       result
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr> 
1 a     a1    a2    <chr [1]> none  
2 b     b1    b2    <chr [1]> b2    
3 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> c1    
4 d     d1    d2    <chr [2]> d2    
5 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> c1
```

When it should return :

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  X     Y     Z     all       result
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr> 
1 a     a1    a2    <chr [1]> none  
2 b     b1    b2    <chr [1]> none    
3 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> c1    
4 d     d1    d2    <chr [2]> d2    
5 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> none
```

Comment: `data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(result = case_when(Y %in% unlist(all) ~ Y,  Z %in% unlist(all) ~ Z,TRUE ~ "none"))` Should do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`all` column actually is a `list`, you cannot directly compare the values in list column.

For example,

```
 "a" %in% list(c("a", "b"))
#[1] FALSE
```

You need `unlist` or `flatten_chr` to make it work.

```
"a" %in% unlist(list(c("a", "b")))
#[1] TRUE

"a" %in% flatten_chr(list(c("a", "b")))
#[1] TRUE
```

So, now you can do

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(Y %in% flatten_chr(all) ~ Y,
                            Z %in% flatten_chr(all) ~ Z,
                            TRUE ~ "none"))


#  X     Y     Z     all      result
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr> 
#1 a     a1    a2    <chr [2]> none  
#2 b     b1    b2    <chr [1]> none  
#3 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> c1    
#4 d     d1    d2    <chr [2]> d2
```

**EDIT**

You could add `rowwise` to compare the values for each row.

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = case_when(Y %in% all ~ Y,
                            Z %in% all ~ Z,
                            TRUE ~ "none"))


# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  X     Y     Z     all       result
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <list>    <chr> 
#1 a     a1    a2    <chr [1]> none  
#2 b     b1    b2    <chr [1]> none  
#3 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> c1    
#4 d     d1    d2    <chr [2]> d2    
#5 c     c1    c2    <chr [2]> none
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to work as I expect either. This my bad I didn't put the correct data for reproducibility.

It seems that any operation on the "all" column operates in ALL the values of the column and not only the values of a row. I'll edit my post to be clearer.

Comment: @Meshuggahat We can add `rowwise`, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I  have used `ifelse` and `mapply` and `any` to go through the list and generating the values based on the given conditions as shown below

```
data$result <- ifelse(unlist(mapply(
  data$all,data$Z,
  FUN =  function(x, y) {
    any(x%in% y)
  }
)), data$Z, ifelse(unlist(mapply(
  data$all, data$Y,
  FUN =  function(x, y) {
    any(x%in% y)
  }
)), data$Y, "none"))

#View Data
data
```

alternatively:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(unlist(mapply(
    all,Z,
    FUN =  function(x,y) {
      any(x%in% y)
    }
  )), Z, ifelse(unlist(mapply(
    all,Y,
    FUN =  function(x, y) {
      any(x%in% y)
    }
  )), Y, "none")))
```

This produces

[image]