# replace values in list-column based on named vector

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tibble

Given the following `df`(or `tibble`) with a `list-column`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(letters, 7),
                 b = sample(letters, 7),
                 c = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no"),
                 list_col = I(list(c(1, 2, 3), "hjhj", c(1, 4), "kkjkj", c(3, 4), "jkj", c(1, 2))))
df
#   a b   c list_col
# 1 y r yes  1, 2, 3
# 2 d s  no     hjhj
# 3 g a yes     1, 4
# 4 a u  no    kkjkj
# 5 b w yes     3, 4
# 6 k j  no      jkj
# 7 n n  no     1, 2

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ a       : chr  "y" "d" "g" "a" ...
#  $ b       : chr  "r" "s" "a" "u" ...
#  $ c       : chr  "yes" "no" "yes" "no" ...
#  $ list_col:List of 7
#   ..$ : num  1 2 3
#   ..$ : chr "hjhj"
#   ..$ : num  1 4
#   ..$ : chr "kkjkj"
#   ..$ : num  3 4
#   ..$ : chr "jkj"
#   ..$ : num  1 2
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

I want to replace `list_col` values with the names of the corresponding values from a look up table but only for  rows where column `c == "yes"`

```
#named lookup
c_yes_column_look_up <- c("number1" = 1,
                          "number2" = 2,
                          "number3" = 3, 
                          "number4" = 4)
```

so my final `df` looks like:

```
df_final
#   a b   c     list_col
# 1 y r yes number1,....
# 2 d s  no         hjhj
# 3 g a yes number1,....
# 4 a u  no        kkjkj
# 5 b w yes number3,....
# 6 k j  no          jkj
# 7 n n  no         1, 2

str(df_final)
# 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ a       : chr  "y" "d" "g" "a" ...
#  $ b       : chr  "r" "s" "a" "u" ...
#  $ c       : chr  "yes" "no" "yes" "no" ...
#  $ list_col:List of 7
#   ..$ : chr  "number1" "number2" "number3"
#   ..$ : chr "hjhj"
#   ..$ : chr  "number1" "number4"
#   ..$ : chr "kkjkj"
#   ..$ : chr  "number3" "number4"
#   ..$ : chr "jkj"
#   ..$ : num  1 2
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

I was thinking something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276854/4083743) but cant quite figure it out:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  #rowwise() %>%
  mutate(list_col = case_when(c == "yes" & list_col %in% c_yes_column_look_up ~ names(list_col[list_col %in% c_yes_column_look_up]),
                                                        TRUE ~ list_col))
```

open to other approaches too, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named vector should be reversed.   We could use either `rowwise` or `map2` (but `map2` may be more efficient).  Loop over the 'list_col' and elements of 'c', create a condition where the 'c' value is 'yes', then do the name matching (on the reversed name vector) with vector values, `coalesce` (if there are NAs) to return the original vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 <- df %>% 
    mutate(list_col = map2(list_col, c, ~ if(.y %in% 'yes')
          unname(coalesce(setNames(names(c_yes_column_look_up), 
              c_yes_column_look_up)[.x], as.character(.x))) else .x))
```

-ouptut

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ a       : chr  "y" "d" "g" "a" ...
 $ b       : chr  "r" "s" "a" "u" ...
 $ c       : chr  "yes" "no" "yes" "no" ...
 $ list_col:List of 7
  ..$ : chr  "number1" "number2" "number3"
  ..$ : chr "hjhj"
  ..$ : chr  "number1" "number4"
  ..$ : chr "kkjkj"
  ..$ : chr  "number3" "number4"
  ..$ : chr "jkj"
  ..$ : num  1 2
```

Comment: one follow up question, if there was an `NA` in `c`, how would you handle it e.g. `df <- data.frame(a = sample(letters, 8),
                 b = sample(letters, 8),
                 c = c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", NA),
                 list_col = I(list(c(1, 2, 3), "hjhj", c(1, 4), "kkjkj", c(3, 4), "jkj", c(1, 2), "hjhjkh")))`

Comment: @user63230 if you meant to return TRUE/FALSE use `%In%` instead of `==` which returns NA where NA is present updated

Comment: sorry, there was a typo, I meant `%in%` instead of `%In%`